# analytics.js script adjustment

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have this script which works together with Analytics Asynchronous ga.js.

```
<script>
(function (tos) {
  window.setInterval(function () {
    tos = (function (t) {
      return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' + (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);
    })(tos.split(':').reverse());
    window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
  }, 10000);
})('00');
</script>
```

I'm trying to adjust it to Analytics Universal tracking code, analytics.js.

I think most of this script will work for analytics.js, but the line that won't work is this

```
window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
```

I'm not sure if the window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent part also works for analytics.js.
The last part of the line can be changed to ga('send', 'event', 'Time', 'Log', tos); I presume?

Would this work in analytics.js? And if not, what should I replace it with?

```
window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : ga('send', 'event', 'Time', 'Log', tos);
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing 3 different GA versions.. `pageTracker` is the old OLD urchin.js script. `_gaq` is the last version using ga.js. `ga()` is the new version using analytics.js

Comment: Would this line work if I only write: ga('send', 'event', 'Time', 'Log', tos);

Comment: define "work". What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: Work means that the code is printed on the page and I am able to see the results in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
```

You see this line in a lot of analytics event tracking tweaks.

To break it down it means:

pageTracker = part of the urchin.js tracking code 
_gaq.push = part of the ga.js tracking code

The code used in the question was written in April 2011 when people still used the urchin and the newer asynchronous syntax (ga.js). These days people don't use the urchin code anymore and the line at the top can be written as

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
```

The line at the top means:
if you use pageTracker (=urchin) print the code `pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos)` and if not use `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);`

If you are using the latest tracking code (analytics.js) you can use: `ga('send', 'event', 'Time', 'Log', tos);`

The whole code would look like this:

```
<script>
(function (tos) {
  window.setInterval(function () {
    tos = (function (t) {
      return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' + (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);
    })(tos.split(':').reverse());
    ga('send', 'event', 'Time', 'Log', tos);
  }, 10000);
})('00');
</script>
```